# Having CSS in Chrome

Tags: html, css

My CSS was working fine in Chrome and IE. I created an FAQ page using tables and identified the tables in CSS classes because I wanted them to have different styles.

When I test it (not live) it works fine in Chrome and IE. When I upload it live, these classes do not apply at all in Chrome, but they do in IE. What have I done wrong?

Here's the new Code:

```css
.table1 {
  width: 80%;
  border-spacing: 4px;
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", serif;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.table1 a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.table1 a:link {
  color: #282828;
}

.table1 a:visited {
  color: #f8daf5;
}

.table1 a:hover {
  color: #a01f52;
}

.tabel2 {
  width: 80%;
  border-spacing: 4px;
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", serif;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.table2 a {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.table2 a:link {
  color: #282828;
}

.table2 a:visited {
  color: #f8daf5;
}

.table2 a:hover {
  color: #a01f52;
}

.table2 th {
  color: #000000;
  text-align: left;
}

.table2 ul {
  list-style-type: square;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <h1 id="top">FAQ</h1>
  <table class="table1">
    <tr>
      <td class="underline"><a href="#how">How do I order?</a></td>
    </tr>
  </table><br><br><br><br>
  <table class="table2">
    <tr>
      <th id="how">How do I order?</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

I didn't include ALL the list because it's very long

http://superstarsofra.com/faq.html

Is the specific page I am talking about. What have I done wrong?

Comment: I see `.tabel2` in the CSS vs `class="table2">` in the HTML

Comment: Did you check if it's cache problem?

Comment: Not sure how to check if it's a cache problem? Just clear out my browser maybe?

Comment: Ahh a spelling error - going to check

Comment: Fixed the spelling, but it did not fix the problem.

Comment: Cleared by browser stuff and it's working. Amazing how it was something so simple and I've spent hours trying to figure it out.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

once go refresh cache by <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f5</kbd>. may be their is cache problem..